# Do something in a rake task before Rails models are loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, delayed-job, sunspot

I have a rake task that works with models. But I need to tell the models that they are being used from Rake instead of within the app. My best idea is to set an environment variable on the command line before running the rake task, but that requires everyone on the team to remember to use the environment variable. Specifically, I have an if statement to skip loading `Delayed::Job`'s `handle_asynchronously` while running the rake task.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :title
    text :title, :content
  end
  handle_asynchronously unless ENV['MIGRATINGDATA']
end
```

When we run our migration task we do this:

`MIGRATINGDATA=true bundle exec rake project:migrate_data`

I'd like to get rid of the need for the special addition to the command line. Our migration code loads a fake Sunspot instance to turn off indexing while migrating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set something at the top of your `Rakefile`:

```
ENV['HELLO_RAKE'] = true

require_relative 'config/application'

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Instead of using `ENV` you could, if you wanted, set a constant, e.g. `HELLO_RAKE = true` and then check `defined?(HELLO_RAKE)`.

An alternative is to just check if the running program is `rake`:

```
handle_asynchronously unless File.basename($0) == "rake"
```

A downside to both of these approaches is that they will be in effect any time you're using Rake, which will include other Rake tasks not related to migrations.

Comment: This looks like it will work! I gave it a try and seems to be working as expected. I used the ENV and it is being loaded and set before the models. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your models care if you are using them from a rake task or not, you are doing something wrong. Instead you can add parameters to certain methods for example. In your specific use case, you can run jobs immediately instead. Put this at the start of your rake task:

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

Comment: Good point about the models shouldn't care if they are in a rake or not. Normally I would agree, but in this case, we are migrating data in and don't need this one particular line to run because we will take care of it after the migration. This will only be done once. After successful deployment this code will be removed. However, we need this around in development until we actually deploy. `delayed_jobs = false` doesn't help. I am open to alternatives.